# Como encurtar condições que usam "or"

Tags: c++, if, condição, else

Quando escrevo condições que usam `or` (`||`), geralmente tenho que ficar escrevendo `if letra igual a (x) ou letra igual a (y) ou letra igual a (z)...`, exatamente como está no código (e só tem apenas cinco condições).

Existe alguma forma de encurtar esses comandos para que não fique um texto gigante dentro das parênteses do `if`?

```
if (letra == 'a' || letra == 'e' || letra == 'i' || letra == 'o' || letra == 'u')
{
    cout << "Essa letra e uma vogal. ";
}
else
{
    cout << "Essa letra e uma consoante. ";
}
```

Comment: teria de ter algum operar como `in`, pelo que vejoa está usando `c`, não há isso nessa linguagem. Entenda que, uma operação lógica precisar ser completa, logo `letra=='a' || letra=='b'` parece meio exgerado, mas imagina que fosse algo diferente como `letra=='a' || idade==18` , note que aqui faz toda a diferença escrever as expressões completas, pq uma condição usa a variável "letra" e outra a variável "idade", por isso as expressões precisam ser completas e claras

Comment: Texto gigante não é problema, pois o código vai ser compilado. Tem maneiras de escanear um valor em uma lista, mas fica pior pelo custo desnecessário durante a execução. Como comentado pelo @RicardoPontual, também varia de acordo com a linguagem, o `in` é um operador comum em algumas para verificar se um valor é parte de uma lista. Dificilmente vai ter opção melhor para esse caso específico seu, se o código for só isso. Em outros cenários pode ter alternativas, ex:sequência `abcde` pode fazer `(var >= 'a' && var <= 'e')`, mas não se aplica no seu caso, e ai não é encurtar, é usar outra lógica.

Comment: Nesse caso, pra ficar melhor organizado, acho que a melhor opção seria um Switch case https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp

Answer (score -3):

Uma opção seria adicionar em um *array*, e com base neste *array* verificar se o item está presente, aqui está um exemplo:

```
const vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

if (vogais.includes(letra)) {
    console.log('Essa letra é uma vogal.');
} else {
    console.log('Essa letra é uma consoante.');
}
```

Comment: Em cenários em que o array muda dinamicamente, buscar o valor com o includes (ou equivalente na linguagem em questão) pode ser útil, mas com valores fixos sai mais caro o custo da busca do que usar `==` e `||` - Ainda, vale notar que aparentemente a pergunta tem um código em C++, não se aplicaria a solução apresentada (mas isso é detalhe, mesmo em JS ainda parece o caso de manter os `==` , e em caso de uma lista mais extensa de valores ver se consegue resolver com comparação de range, e por último busca)

Comment: O código da pergunta é C++ e o código da resposta é Javascript. Por favor o usuário que deu esse up vote preste mais atenção as publicações que atesta como útil, nesse caso o erro é inofensivo pois o código não compila mas existem casos onde erros similares levam a abertura de brechas de segurança.

Answer (score -3):

se forem apenas cinco comparações ,
até pode deixar do jeito que está mesmo , mas se for muitas , por exemplo umas duzentas , aí uma forma mais simples pode ser usando uma variável para armazenar as opções e um loop para percorrer tais opções , e se para o usuário seja mais fácil , já para o pc será mais trabalhoso e demorado , mas mesmo assim a perda de tempo será em torno de alguns milissegundos .
um exemplo:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char letra = 'x';
    char ax[6] = "aeiou";
    size_t flg = 0;
 ///if (letra == 'a' || letra == 'e' || letra == 'i' || letra == 'o' || 
letra == 'u')
    for    (size_t f=0;f<5;f++) if(ax[f] == letra){flg = 1;break;}
    if(flg){cout << "Essa letra e uma vogal.     ";}
    else   {cout << "Essa letra e uma consoante. ";}
    cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```